# Login to YouTube using WebRequests in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, youtube

I'm fairly new to using WebRequests in C# and would like some help logging into YouTube and storing cookies into a cookie container. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the .NET client library (http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) then it will take care of authenticating for you when needed using the credentials you provided:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Authentication

**GData in C#**

When using the GData API there's no explicit logout method, you can invalidate your token but it will also expire after some time if you don't use it. Specific details on how to invalidate the token differ according to the authentication mechanism adopted (OAuth, AuthSub, ClientLogin).

You can also refer to this article on CodeProject, [Manage YouTube using C# and Youtube API 1.6](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143669/Manage-YouTube-using-C-and-Youtube-API-1-6)

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService();
service.setUserCredentials(txtUser.Text , txtPassword.Text);
try { service.QueryClientLoginToken(); }
catch(System.Net.WebException e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); }
```

**ADDED:** I have tweaked below code to match your requirement.

```
class YouTube
{
    public void Login()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = GetNewRequest("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth", cookies);
        request.Referer = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252F&uilel=3&hl=en_US&service=youtube";
        request.Host = "accounts.google.com";
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>{
            {"continue","https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252F"},
            {"service","youtube"},{"uilel","3"},{"dsh","157212168103955870"},{"hl","en_US"},
            {"GALX","PTqcwpZb2aE"},{"pstMsg","1"},{"dnConn",""}, {"checkConnection","youtube%3A248%3A1"}, 
            {"checkedDomains","youtube"}, {"timeStmp",""}, {"secTok",""}, {"Email","username"}, {"Passwd","password"}, 
            {"signIn","Sign+in"}, {"PersistentCookie","yes"}, {"rmShown","1"}};
        HttpWebResponse response = MakeRequest(request, cookies, parameters);
        response.Close();
    }

    private static CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

    private static HttpWebRequest GetNewRequest(string targetUrl, CookieContainer SessionCookieContainer)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUrl);
        request.CookieContainer = SessionCookieContainer;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        return request;
    }

    private static HttpWebResponse MakeRequest(HttpWebRequest request, CookieContainer SessionCookieContainer, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
    {
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5Accept: */*";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.CookieContainer = SessionCookieContainer;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string postData = string.Empty;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> parametro in parameters)
        {
            if (postData.Length == 0)                
                postData += String.Format("{0}={1}", parametro.Key, parametro.Value);                
            else                
                postData += String.Format("&{0}={1}", parametro.Key, parametro.Value);                
        }

        byte[] postBuffer = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        SessionCookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);

        while (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
        {
            response.Close();
            request = GetNewRequest(response.Headers["Location"], SessionCookieContainer);
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            SessionCookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/ncl/thread/40d249b5-a9ad-4068-8853-629fb20584a0

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to login using the API and store the details into a cookie container? I will be needing the login data in the cookie container later in the code.

Comment: Check my added code, this will give you fairly good idea how to use it. Happy Coding...

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You should note that GLAX value is generated randomly and is it's new value is required on the posting request, you should first make a request and get the new cookie values and then post them in a new request with the request body, after that it will work.